# Document AI OCR processor returning error 3 Unsupported input file format randomly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am using Google Cloud Document AI for the OCR processor and am randomly running into a code 3 'Unsupported input file format.' error.

I can submit the same file 5 times and this error will come up maybe 1-2 out of the 5 times. The other times, the processor works completely as expected.

I am using the online processor endpoint, and am using PDFBox to split a larger pdf into chunks of 10. I have done a check to verify that the pdf that was sent to Document AI that errored was not corrupt or anything. I have done everything I can to make sure that there is nothing wrong on my end, everything is pointing to something on Document AI. I have researched this error and nothing is standing out as to what could be happening. Any ideas?

Edit:
Some additional information...here is the PDFBox code that I am using to split up a PDF into groups of 10 pages:

```
        File file = new File(doc);
        PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(file);
        Splitter splitter = new Splitter();

        splitter.setSplitAtPage(pageSplits);
        List<PDDocument> splittedList = splitter.split(document);

        List<String> base64List = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (PDDocument listDoc : splittedList) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            listDoc.save(baos);
            String base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
            base64List.add(base64String);
            listDoc.close();
        }

        System.out.println("{\"pages\":" + document.getNumberOfPages() + ", \"pdfs\":[" + wrapWithQuotesAndJoin(base64List)+ "]}");

        document.close();
```

I have never had an issue with the output this produces. Like I said above, whenever I got an 'Unsupported input file format' error from any of the output array, I would convert and save the base64 to disk to check for corruption and the file would never be corrupt.

My code for sending to Document AI:

```
const location = 'us';
...
const name = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}/processors/${processorId}`;
const keys = require('./google-service-account-credentials.json');
// Instantiates a client
const client = new DocumentProcessorServiceClient({
  authClient: new JWT({
    email: keys.client_email,
    key: keys.private_key,
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
  })
});

...
const output = await exec('java -jar ./docSplitter.jar '+ '"'+filePath.replace(/\&/g, "\\$&")+'"', {maxBuffer: 1000000000}); // 1GB buffer
let pages = JSON.parse(output.stdout);
const numSplits = Math.ceil(pages.pages / 10);
... 
  
for(let i=0; i<numSplits; i++) {
  const request = {
    name,
    rawDocument: {
      content: output.pdfs[i],
      mimeType: 'application/pdf',
    },
  };
  try {
    const [result] = await client.processDocument(request);
    console.log("processDocument complete "+i)
  }
  catch(e) {
    // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS BEING CAUGHT
    // THE CODE BELOW SAVES THE 'FAILED' CHUNK AND IS NEVER CORRUPT
    fs.writeFileSync("failedChunk.pdf", json.pdfs[i], 'base64');
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code snippet you used ? Splitting may increase the risk of content corruption. Maybe try another library to split the pdf or consider sending a batch request, if for one doc, as it supports 200 pages at once.

Comment: Can I request for a sample file for this, Also can you provide replication steps for this e.g. Python client library and code snippets as @Yannick mentioned.

Comment: I've actually run into this issue a couple of times as well. Can you please provide the code you're using to send the document and an example file?

If you have an operation ID, that would also be helpful.

Comment: @HoltSkinner I have added code samples of my splitting code and submitting code. I cant provide an example pdf as the documents arent public but the file I am using is 3145 pages.

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed with the product development team that this behavior can occasionally occur with the Release Candidate processor versions for the OCR and Form Parser. But it is a transient issue, and can be resolved by re-calling the API.

It's recommended to use the Stable Processor versions for any production use cases.

We are working on improving clarity of error messages and this flaky `Unsupported file type` is a misleading message that we are addressing.

Answer (score 0):

I've exactly the same error at this time.

```
Google::Cloud::InvalidArgumentError: 3:Unsupported input file format.. debug_error_string:{UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:443 {created_time:"2023-10-18T13:23:38.811535761+02:00", grpc_status:3, grpc_message:"Unsupported input file format."}}
```

See https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/23426